# SSRS Reports: How do I create a monthly/YTD report like this?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have a table that looks like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
CUSTNUM (INT), ITEMNUM (INT), MONTH (INT), YEAR (INT), AMOUNT (INT)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
100000, 489, 1, 2011, 4000
100000, 489, 2, 2011, 3000
100000, 489, 3, 2011, 5000
100000, 587, 1, 2011, 7500
100000, 587, 2, 2011, 6800
100000, 587, 3, 2011, 9000
```

What I'm trying to create is a report that shows me each item a customer has purchased in a given month and year. **On the same page**, I would like a table (either part of the same matrix or whatever is required) that has the Year-to-Date sales grouped by itemnum on each line.

The end result should be a summary-like page (maybe multiple pages) for **each customer** with the monthly sales at the top and a year-to-date summary of each item purchased at the bottom.

Here's what the desired output would look like when queried against March 2011:

```
-----------------------
Customer: 100000
-----------------------
Item    Month Quantity
-----------------------
489     5000
587     9000
-----------------------
Total   14000

------------------------
Item    Year-to-Date Qty
------------------------
489     12000
587     23300
------------------------
Total   35300
```

The next page break would be for a new customer with similar layout.

Specifically, I'm struggling with what the query side of things should look like. I have a working query for the specific month -- and if I omit the MONTH parameter from the where clause, I get all of the rows required for year-to-date -- but then how do I show just the single month up at the top?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe split the question up in smaller questions, include test data and include all fields like the date you are refering to. And expected outcome

Comment: Thanks for replying. I added the requested sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL 2008 R2, use Lookup function. This function is not available in earlier editions.

Keep the data set that you already have. No need to worry about YTD yet.
Create a second data set that finds the YTD for given customer, group by item. Lookup function can find YTD in 2nd data set based on Item number in 1st data set.

Hope this helps.

**Additional answer**

Almost forgot about Sub-Report. You can create a second report that takes 1 parameter: CustNum, and shows YTD in a table. Add this as a Sub-Report to your main report. A good place would be in the table footer.

Comment: That sounds like what I was hoping to find, now I need to check what version of SQL we're using... Will post back. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I was hoping your suggestion would help me solve it, but we're going to be stuck on SQL 2008 for a while (No R2). Is there another way to achieve the same thing? Or can you think of a way to use a row from a dataset in multiple locations (non-adjacent rows) in the same matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Sql is not designed to make the report, it is designed to extract your data so excel, report builder or some other tool can set up the design. I hope you can use this.

```
declare @t TABLE (custnum int, itemnum int, month int, year int, amount int)

DECLARE @m INT
DECLARE @y INT

set @m = 3
set @y = 2011

insert @t values(100000, 489, 1, 2011, 4000)
insert @t values(100000, 489, 2, 2011, 3000)
insert @t values(100000, 489, 3, 2011, 5000)
insert @t values(100000, 587, 1, 2011, 7500)
insert @t values(100000, 587, 2, 2011, 6800)
insert @t values(100000, 587, 3, 2011, 9000)

SELECT custnum customer, itemnum item, sum(amount) [Month Quantity]
FROM @t
WHERE MONTH = @m
AND year = @y
GROUP BY custnum, itemnum with rollup
```

Result:

```
customer  item     month quantity
100000    498      5000
100000    587      9000
100000             14000 <---(total for this customer)
                   14000 <---(grand total for all customers)


SELECT itemnum item, sum(amount) [Year-to-Date Qty]
FROM @t
WHERE year = @y
GROUP BY itemnum with rollup
```

Result:

```
item      Year-to-Date Qty
489       12000
587       23300
          35300
```

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2008 to generate an .rdl file for the SSRS report. Sorry, I wasn't specific in the post since I tagged it with VS2008 and SSRS. I think the crux of the problem that I'm struggling with is how do I sum the months for YTD, yet still retain the values for the single month I'm querying against -- all within the same report definition? I'm using a matrix, but maybe that's the wrong approach?

Comment: totally my bad, i just saw sql. I hope you can use it or some of it anyway, since it is quite close to being the same as you requested